# Rasperrian + MPD: Play/Resume fails

Tags: audio, debian

I'm running a RasperryPi with `Rasperrian` with an installed `MPD`. When i first use an `MPD` client to start the audio playback, it works fine. But then i press pause and resume and nothing happens. The log output is like this:

```
Mar 29 23:48 : output: "MPD PulseAudio Output" [pulse] failed to play: suspended
Mar 29 23:48 : output: "MPD PulseAudio Output" [pulse] failed to play: suspended
Mar 29 23:48 : output: "MPD PulseAudio Output" [pulse] failed to play: suspended
```

The `MPD` is configured to use `Pulse` like this:

```
audio_output {
  type   "pulse"
  name   "MPD PulseAudio Output"
}
```

In `htop` i see this process:

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

when I kill it, it works one time again. Any suggestion please?

Further more the sound crackles sometime while playback. I already configures [this](http://dbader.org/blog/crackle-free-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-mpd-and-pulseaudio) workaround. I also see multiple instances of `MPD` running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it with switching to alsa. It works for me, because i have no other sound output on the device.